# Cannot cast ContentResolver to a string error on the OnItemClickListener Method

Tags: android, listview

I am populating a Listview using a ContentProvider. Meanwhile, upon clicking on the OnItemClickListener() method, I obtain a "cannot cast ContentResolver to a java.lang.string" error. You will find the code regarding the Activity Class below. How could I change the code so that the OnItemClickListener method works properly?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private ListView alarmlv;
DBHelper mydb;

private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.domain.app.alarms";
private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/alarms");

SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "name");
    alarmlv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewAlarms);

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listview_row, cursor,
            new String[]{ mydb.ALARMS_COLUMN_NAME }, new int[]{R.id.alarm_name}, 0);
    alarmlv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    alarmlv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            //obj.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String itemVal =(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putString("name", itemVal);
            Intent intent = new
                    Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayAlarm.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the error, because `CursorAdapter` do not contain `String` elements. It contains elements of type `Cursor`.
Try the following code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItemAtPosition(position);
    String itemVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mydb.ALARMS_COLUMN_NAME));

    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("name", itemVal);
    Intent intent = new
            Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayAlarm.class);
    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nabin! Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @JF0001 glad it could help.